# Windows 8 secure boot unavailable for my PC

Tags: windows, windows-8, secure-boot

When I ran the Windows 8 upgrade assistant, it said secure boot is not available for my PC firmware. I am using Dell XPS 17 L702 on 64-bit. Since I dual boot Linux as well, Is there a way to have the secure boot option available?

Comment: This means your system is not using a UEFI BIOS that supports `Secure Boot`.  Your system in theory could be using UEFI and simply using a revision that doesn't support it.  If thats the case you have no other option but to wait on Dell to release an update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK secure boot will not allow to boot Linux, [there are plans](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2012/10/linux-foundation-to-offer-signed-solution-for-uefi-secure-boot-conundrum/) sign a bootloader which in turn would load existing bootloaders(e.g. GRUB), but it's not done yet.
If you still want to enable it:[image]

Comment: where is linux mentioned here?

Comment: Third sentence: "Since i dual boot Linux as well"

Comment: my bad. He still dosen't actually have a secure boot option though. While its part of the UEFI spec, it wasn't common pre windows 8)

Comment: [His hardware might support it](http://forum.notebookreview.com/lenovo/694159-x220-windows-8-uefi.html#post8912140), but it's too hard to guess [which model does he have](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dell_xps) to give a more complete answer.

Comment: @Page4096 I have the XPS 17 L702 Model

Comment: [Here's an article](http://communities.intel.com/community/vproexpert/blog/2012/06/26/microsoft-windows-8--enabling-secure-boot) that addresses this problem in the "Enabling secure boot" section(can't paste it here because of the character limit).

Answer (score 1):

Secure boot is something baked into the [UEFI bootloader](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#Secure_boot) (calling it a 'bios' would be inaccurate but it does the same thing) and is an option the OEM needs to enable. If your system dosen't have it already, you'd likely need a new UEFI version that supports it for your PC.

You can't just turn it 'on' on an existing system, and chances are unless you buy a system with windows 8 preinstalled and secure boot in place, you can't 'just' enable it

Comment: Any US citizens wishing to file an anti-trust complaint about this can do so here: http://www.justice.gov/atr/contact/newcase.html

Answer (score 1):

Secure boot is a technology described by recent revisions of the UEFI specification; it offers the prospect of a hardware-verified, malware-free operating system and improve the security of many system deployments.

The Linux Foundation has come up with a solution that should work for any and all operating systems.

When Linux Foundation is able to obtain a SecureBoot key from Microsoft, they will release this new pre-bootloader on their web-site.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to update your motherboard "BIOS". That is what I had to do with my "DELL Vostro 470" PC that I had bought in June. I suggest that you go to the DELL website and go to the "Driver Download" section to find out whether your PC is suitable for an update. You will need your DELL Service Tag information. If you do an upgrade be very careful not to interrupt the process. You could leave the motherboard in an inoperable state. After the update the default state is "Secure Boot Disabled". On my PC I repeatedly hit the F12 key during power up to get into the "Boot Option menu" where I could change that to Secure Boot Enabled and also change to make my CD drive the first boot device instead of the HDD.